# Rails not sending (ical) attachments in emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I'm trying to send an email with an ical attachment, I'm running `rails v.3.2.13` and using the `icalendar` gem (to generate the ical string) [see](http://www.sentia.com.au/blog/sending-an-ical-as-attachment-in-rails-3). (In development mode in case that might be a problem).

The relevant mailer code looks like this:

```
def mailme
  ical = Icalendar::Calendar.new
  ...
  attachments["meetings.ics"] = { mime_type: "text/calendar", content: ical.to_ical }
  mail(from: email, to: recipient, ...)
end
```

there is also template file with the same name (mailme.html.erb)

The problem is the mail (html) is send without the attachment.
As usual any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else stumbles upon this.

If you are using delayed_job check out https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#wiki-Sending_emails_with_attachments

To fix this, remember to add this line to your mailer:

```
content_type "multipart/mixed"
```

Answer (score 3):

I've gotten them working with something like below:

```
mail.attachments['meeting.ics'] = { mime_type: 'application/ics',
                                    content: ical.to_ical }
mail(from: email, to: recipient, ...)
```

So it's possible you need to call it on `#attachments` on the `mail` object instead of calling it on the current context. I'm not sure if your mime type *needs* to be application/ics, but that's worked fine for me in my systems.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Hi, turns out my problem had something to do with the fact that the mails were pushed on our queue (delayed job) and it's a well known problem (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#wiki-Sending_emails_with_attachments). Regards